# How to detect end of input with pipes

Tags: haskell, haskell-pipes

I'm trying to read a group of up to 50 items from a pipe and process them in an IO action all at once. (The use case for this is I'm trying to insert data into a database and I want to do an entire batch inside one transaction because it is vastly more efficient). Here is a simplified version of what I've got so far:

```
type ExampleType = Int

doSomething :: [ExampleType] -> IO ()
doSomething = undefined

inGroupsOf50 :: Monad m => Producer ExampleType m () -> m ()
inGroupsOf50 input =
    runEffect $ input >-> loop
        where loop = do entries <- replicateM 50 await
                    lift $ doSomething entries  --Insert a bunch all in one transaction
                    loop
```

The problem is as far as I can tell, unless the number of items to insert happens to divide by 50, I'm going to miss some. What I really want instead of `replicateM 50 await` is something that gives me up to 50 items or fewer if the input ends but I can't quite figure out how to write that.

I've been thinking that [pipes-parse](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/pipes-parse) might be the right library to be looking at. `draw` looks to have a promising signature... but so far all the bits aren't fitting together in my head. I have a `producer`, I'm writing a `consumer` and I don't really get how that relates to the concept of a `parser`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Even more than [`pipes-parse`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/pipes-parse) you quite possibly want to take a look at [`pipes-group`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/pipes-group). In particular, let's  examine the function

```
-- this type is slightly specialized
chunksOf 
  :: Monad m => 
     Int -> 
     Lens' (Producer a m x) (FreeT (Producer a m) m x)
```

The `Lens'` bit is perhaps scary but can be eliminated quickly: it states that we can convert `Producer a m x` to `FreeT (Producer a m) m x`[0]

```
import Control.Lens (view)

chunkIt :: Monad m => Int -> Producer a m x -> FreeT (Producer a m) m x
chunkIt n = view (chunksOf n)
```

So now we have to figure out what to do with that `FreeT` bit. In particular, we're going to want to dig into the [`free`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/free) package and pull out the function `iterT`

```
iterT
  :: (Functor f, Monad m) => 
     (f (m a) -> m a) -> 
     (FreeT f m a -> m a)
```

This function, `iterT`, let's us "consume" a `FreeT` one "step" at a time. To understand this, we'll first specialize the type of `iterT` to replace `f` with `Producer a m`

```
runChunk :: Monad m =>
            (Producer a m (m x)       -> m x) ->
            (FreeT (Producer a m) m x -> m x)
runChunk = iterT
```

In particular, `runChunk` can "run" a `FreeT` full of `Producer`s so long as we tell it how to convert a `Producer a m (m x)` into an `m`-action. *This* may start to look more familiar. When we define the first argument of `runChunk` we simply have to execute a `Producer` which, in this case, will have no more than the selected number of elements.

But what is up with the effectful return value `m x`? It's the "continuation", e.g. all of the chunks which come *after* the current one you're writing. So, for instance, let's assume we've got a `Producer` of `Char`s and we'd like to print and linebreak after 3 characters

```
main :: IO ()
main = flip runChunk (chunkIt 3 input) $ \p -> _
```

The `_` hole at this point has type `IO ()` with `p` in the context at type `p :: Producer Char IO (IO ())`. We can consume this pipe with `for`, gather its return type (which is the continuation, again), emit a newline, and then run the continuation.

```
input :: Monad m => Producer Char m ()
input = each "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"

main :: IO ()
main = flip runChunk (chunkIt 3 input) $ \p -> do
  cont <- runEffect $ for p (lift . putChar)
  putChar '\n'
  cont
```

And this behaves exactly as desired

```
λ> main
abc
def
ghi
jkl
mno
pqr
stu
vwx
yz
```

---

To be clear, while I did a bit of exposition, this is fairly simple code once you see how all the pieces fit together. Here is the whole listing:

```
input :: Monad m => Producer Char m ()
input = each "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"

main :: IO ()
main = flip iterT (input ^. chunksOf 3) $ \p -> do
  cont <- runEffect $ for p $ \c -> do
    lift (putChar c)
  putChar '\n'
  cont
```

[0] Also a bit more than that, but it's enough for now.